# Flutter CupertinoDatePicker - can I swap month and day positions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to use `CupertinoDatePicker`, however its date formatting is `mm-dd-yyyy`, which in fact is not common for a specific location, where my app will be distributed. I would like to change the format to `dd-mm-yyyy`, which IMO seems more general.
Is that possible, using that picker?

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: It should be possible in [Flutter version 1.7](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-7-9cab4f34eacf)*

According to the [CupertinoDatePicker documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html):

> the class will display its children as
>   consecutive columns. **Its children order is based on
>   internationalization**.

You can read more about [internationalization Flutter apps here](http://flutter%20internationalization%20tutorial).

You need to add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

And then in your root widget add proper localizationsDelegates:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Application',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''),
          const Locale('fr', ''),
      ],
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
      ),        
    );
  }
}
```

If you'll use in app one of the localizations that supports `dd-mm-yyyy` format, e.g. UK English, and you'll have this language set on your device, you should see this widget changed accordingly.

Comment: Well, this might be what doc says, however, it does not work at all!

Comment: Right, it looks like there's an open issue for this in fluter repository: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13452